# Saving chat History using QuickBlox

Tags: java, android

How to save chat history in application using Quickblox android sdk 1.2 ?

I have build an 1:1 chat application using QuickBlox sdk 1.2 ,and I am not able to save the chat history of users.
So, please provide me the steps to save chat history.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QBChatMessage chatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
chatMessage.setBody("Hi there");
chatMessage.setProperty("save_to_history", "1");
```

Here "save_to_history" is used to save chat messages to history and user can request a chat history for particular dialog.

and you can get help from this [LINK](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample) .

Hope this helps :)